# Defining the probability distribution of a Random vector given the probability over a "sub-vector"

Tags: distributions, estimation, pca, stationarity, computer-vision

Suppose I want the probability distribution over a random vector $X={X_1 ,X_2 ... X_n }$.

What I already have with me is the distribution over a subvector $X_i , X_{i+1}...X_m$, $m<n$ which I know is stationary over $i$. i.e. the subvector $X_1 , X_2 ... X_m$ abides by the same distribution as $X_3 , X_4 .... X_{m+2}$.

Can I make any claim about the distribution of a larger vector made from these random variables $X_1 , X_2 ... X_n$ where $n>m$?

My motivation for this is from computer vision. Suppose I have the PCA components over patches of size $m\times m$, so I can calculate the probability of any $m\times m$ patch given to me. But now, I'd like to analyze the probability of $n\times n$ patches using this knowledge of about $m\times m$ patches. Of course, I could calculate the PCA of $n\times n$ patches, but I am curious about thinking about this in this manner.

Comment: From a general perspective, you cannot determine the joint distribution of a vector from its marginals.